# JFrame Background Image JButtons

Tags: java

This is my main: 
I am trying to get `Ship.png` image appearing in the JFrame to be underlying my JButtons. Currently it is above all of my buttons and is masking over everything. I can't seem to find a way to push the image behind my JButtons.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.io.*;
import javax. imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Project2_JoshuaLucas
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame main_frame = new JFrame("Select a Cabin or Suite!"); // Sets title for the JFrame

    try {

    main_frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(newFile("Ship.png")))));

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Image doesn't exist.");
    }

    main_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Closes JFrame when exiting

    Cabin_Choice choice = new Cabin_Choice("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0.00); // Calls the constructor of my Cabin_Choice class
    main_frame.getContentPane().add(choice); // Places choice into the current JFrame pane

    main_frame.pack(); // Sizes the frame
    main_frame.setVisible(true); // Allows us to see the frame

  } // Ends the main method
} // Ends the class
```

And this is my 2nd file for the main.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Suite_Selector extends JPanel
{
  final private JLabel description;
  final private JRadioButton cabin1;
    description = new JLabel ("Please select the cabin/suite you'll be staying in:");

    cabin1 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-1");

  cabin1.setBackground(Color.gray); //Background color

  ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
  group.add(cabin1);

  Cabin_Listener the_cabin = new Cabin_Listener();

  cabin1.addActionListener(the_cabin);

  add(description);
  add(cabin1);

      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
  }
```

Comment: Your code example is incomplete, so it's impossible to 100% sure why you're having difficulties. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Sorry, im a bit new here. Is this better? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Based on your code example Suite_Selector isn't used, but Cabin_Choice is missing